Android compose: offset at a fraction of parent size
I want to place some composables at specific positions on top of an image. However, the image will be responsive (it will resize), so I can't use Modifier.offset(some_fixed_offset.dp).
Modifier.offset(10.percent) would be ideal, but that doesn't work (or does it?).
How can I implement this?
These are the possible paths that I examined briefly:

BoxWithConstraints has min/max size, but I would need the exact size to calculate the relative positions myself.
A custom composable might do, but, at first glance, it's also not evident to get the actual parent size. It rather informs the parent of it's desired inner size.

Before I dive into the custom solution, is there an easier way, similar to .offset(10.percent)?
Here's some test code that I started with:
@Composable
fun GeneralPlaceHolder(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box (
        modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .size(300.dp) //<-- if this size changes, 
                          //    the yellow dot should hold it's relative position
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .fillMaxSize()) {
            DaThing()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DaThing() {
    Box {
        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.testgrid10x10), 
           contentDescription = "", 
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(5.dp)
            .offset(x = 10.dp, y=20.dp) //<-- percentage no can do?
            .background(Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}

And a screenshot with a grid as the "image". It's a 10x10 grid, so offset(10.percent, 10.percent) would place the yellow dot at the first grid point.


Please edit your question and add testgrid10x10 image.

@AdnanHabib, it could have been a picture of a kitten - it really is irrelevant. The solution should work with any picture, graphic or composable in general. The grid is an xml resource with a <vector> element. It's just something I quickly build in Adobe Illustrator -> .svg -> Android Studio > New> Vector asset" > .xml

Modifier.offset() changes placeable placement based on fixed values via parameters as
private class OffsetNode(
    var x: Dp,
    var y: Dp,
    var rtlAware: Boolean
) : LayoutModifierNode, Modifier.Node() {

    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        return layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            if (rtlAware) {
                placeable.placeRelative(x.roundToPx(), y.roundToPx())
            } else {
                placeable.place(x.roundToPx(), y.roundToPx())
            }
        }
    }
}

By changing placeable.placeRelative(x.roundToPx(), y.roundToPx()) to percentage of parent Constraints with Modifier.layout{} you can place your Composable to value in percentage based on parent.
However the thing you need to pay attention is it should be the Constraints coming from parent which means where you put Modifier.layout{} matters. If you set it after any size, offset or padding Modifier, Constraints might change since size and padding Modifiers do exact same thing based on their inner logic. If you wish to learn about how Constraints, layout and size modifiers work you can refer this answer.

@Preview
@Composable
fun GeneralPlaceHolderTest() {
    GeneralPlaceHolder()
}

@Composable
fun GeneralPlaceHolder(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column {

        var percentage by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0f)
        }

        Slider(
            value = percentage,
            onValueChange = {
                percentage = it
            }
        )

        Text("Percentage: $percentage")

        Box(
            modifier
                .background(Color.Red)
                .size(300.dp) //<-- if this size changes,
                //    the yellow dot should hold it's relative position
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                DaThing(percentage)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DaThing(percentage: Float) {
    Box {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().drawBehind {
                drawRect(color = Color.Blue)
            }
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.placeRelative(
                            x = (constraints.maxWidth * percentage).toInt(),
                            y = (constraints.maxHeight * percentage).toInt()
                        )
                    }
                }
                .size(5.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}

This layout also can be refactored as Modifier
fun Modifier.offsetByPercent(percentage: Float) = this.then(
    Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.placeRelative(
                x = (constraints.maxWidth * percentage).toInt(),
                y = (constraints.maxHeight * percentage).toInt()
            )
        }
    }
)

And can be used as
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .offsetByPercent(percentage)
        .size(5.dp)
        .background(Color.Yellow)
)


A perfectly working example, thank you. I need a dozen or so of these relatively placed objects, so I'll wrap that inner box in a small custom composable.

You can turn this into a Modifier like offset if you want to. I didn't do RtL check as Modifier or check for percentage to be in 0..1f range but these can be easily added.

As I'm fairly new to Kotlin - you just introduced me to extension functions :)
And this extended modifier function is exactly what I'm going to use, though with a separate percentage for x and y.

Expanding on Thracian's answer, I ended up creating a custom composable in addition to the custom modifier. Reason is that the modifier relies on the parent being of the same size and position as the image that I want to place composables on top of. Since it's difficult to force the parent to wrap content (it tends to fill all available space), I really needed to have the overlay based on the image's position and size rather than the parent. Hence a custom composable where we use the intrinsic size of the image to calculate where it will effectively be painted inside the Image composable, namely at the center of it:
@Composable
fun PercentageImageOverlay(painter: Painter,
                           overlay: @Composable () -> Unit,
                           modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
                           ) {
    val image = @Composable {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
        )
    }
    Layout(contents = listOf(image) + overlay, modifier) {
            (imageMeasureables, overlayMeasureables), constraints ->


        val imagePlaceable = imageMeasureables.first().measure(constraints)
        //newConstraints = size of Image() composable.
        val imgW = imagePlaceable.width.toFloat()
        val imgH = imagePlaceable.height.toFloat()
        //intrinsic size of the image to be painted gives us the aspect ratio.
        val intrW = painter.intrinsicSize.width.toFloat()
        val intrH = painter.intrinsicSize.height.toFloat()
        //1. get both aspect ratios. If ratio > 1 : a high shape (portrait)
        val imgRatio= imgH/imgW
        val paintRatio = intrH/intrW

        // figure out where image will be painted.
        val paintInImageW: Float
        val paintInImageH: Float

        if( paintRatio > imgRatio) { // painting higher than image. Resize painting to fit the image height.
            paintInImageH = imgH // = intrH * (imgH / intrH)
            paintInImageW = intrW * (imgH / intrH)
        } else {
            paintInImageW = imgW // = intrW * (imgW / intrW)
            paintInImageH = intrH * (imgW / intrW)
        }

        val newConstraints = Constraints(0, paintInImageW.toInt(), 
                                         0, paintInImageH.toInt())

        val overlayPlaceables = overlayMeasureables.map { it.measure(newConstraints) }

        val offsetX = (imgW - paintInImageW) / 2
        val offsetY = (imgH - paintInImageH) / 2

        layout(imagePlaceable.width, imagePlaceable.height) {
            imagePlaceable.place(0, 0)
            overlayPlaceables.map { it.place(offsetX.toInt(), offsetY.toInt()) }
        }

    }
}

Combined with a slightly modified modifier that also forces a percentage size on the composable:
fun Modifier.placeByPercent(percentageX: Float, percentageY: Float, percentageW: Float, percentageH: Float) = this.then(
    Modifier.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val width = (constraints.maxWidth * percentageW).toInt()
        val height = (constraints.maxHeight * percentageH).toInt()
        val placeable = measurable.measure(Constraints(width, width, height, height))
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place(
                x = (constraints.maxWidth * percentageX).toInt(),
                y = (constraints.maxHeight * percentageY).toInt()
            )
        }
    }
)

Below an (almost) previewable example. It uses 2 images that can easily be removed or replaced.
It also tests a valid concern that Thracian had: the modifier by itself fails with a right-to-left layout. However, the custom composable seems to fix that:
@Composable
fun GeneralPlaceHolder(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Surface(
        modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .size(bigSize)
    ) {
            val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.testgrid10x10)
            PercentageImageOverlay(painter,
                overlay =  @Composable {
                    SomeOverlay(percentageX = .1f, percentageY = .2f,
                                percentageWidth = .1f, percentageHeight = .1f)
                    SomeOverlay(percentageX = .5f, percentageY = .4f,
                                percentageWidth = .2f, percentageHeight = .2f)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            )
    }
}

@Composable
fun SomeOverlay(percentageX: Float, percentageY: Float, 
                percentageWidth: Float, percentageHeight: Float) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .placeByPercent(percentageX, percentageY, 
                            percentageWidth, percentageHeight)
            .background(Color.Green)
    ) {
        Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.someCircle), contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}

val bigSize = 200.dp

@Preview(name = "Left-To-Right", locale = "en")
@Preview(name = "Right-To-Left", locale = "ar")
annotation class LayoutDirectionPreviews

@LayoutDirectionPreviews
@Preview()
@Composable
fun ThePreview(
) {
    Ears2Theme {
        GeneralPlaceHolder(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(bigSize) //<-- if this size changes, everything should still work.
        )
    }
}


I'm sure no one is going to use this code to decorate pictures of kittens with pink stars and such...

Hi I'm fairly new to android and kotlin/java but I am trying to implement your solution to solve my use case, seen here open question. In my case I need to also get the correct offset values on click and was trying to figure out how to use the PercentageImageOverlay composable as a function that would return the percentage float values whenever clicking anywhere on an image. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

I see, you want to add markers. Well, my circles in the above image are indeed like markers on the grid. So, my example should work for you. In order to detect a click you can make almost any composable clickable via the modifiers. What is missing in my example is the full App of course and some drawable resources but that's outside the scope of this question.
